# How to Select an image in one field, gets selected into another field also?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I have two image fields (OR file field) on the page in a form.

I want to select an image from my computer in one image field, also gets selected into that second image field so that when I save the form, it also saved in that second image field.

Is it possible with jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the `input[type=file]` `value` property, except to clear it, so this is also the only way to edit its `files` property.

But you can use the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) for when you save your second form.

Then you just have to [`append(input2.name, input1.files[0])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) in this FormData object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element. You can use `FormData` to submit same image multiple times.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file-1", file, file.name);
fd.append("file-2", file, file.name);
```

Comment: héhé *Great minds think alike.*  Just a note though, when you append a File, you should not need to explicitly set the name param of `append()`, that's one of the only usefulness of the File object (with `lastModified`), let's use it ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Using third parameter allows setting different `filename` at `"multipart/form-data"` without creating new `File` object.

Comment: Yes I know :-) It's just that here it useless because File objects, contrary to Blobs already have this name which is passed to the formdata. So you don't **need** to set it. Actually append (Xxx,blob,name) will create new File (blob, name) but new File (File, File.name) is useless.